# Как на JMeter написать сценарий, в котором в javascript коде будет вычисляться некоторое значение и подставляться в URL?

Tags: jmeter

Всем привет. Проблема вот какая:

1. Есть задача выполнения нагрузочного тестирования апи некого функционала https://api-test.ua/api/1/json/6/${CURRENT_TIME_MS}/${SIGNATURE}
2. В препосте нужно вычислить текущее время в мс (но это можно подставить сразу ${__time(,)}) и сгенерить ключ шифрования с помощью CryptoJS
3. Шифрование выполняется в js-скрипте, типа такого:

var secret = "some_string_key_for_encoding";
var sign = CryptoJS.SHA1(CURRENT_TIME_MS + secret + body + secret);

и body = {
    "timeout": 1,
    "arr": [{"q": true}, {"w": false}]
}

далее значение CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(sign) нужно присвоить переменной ${SIGNATURE} и подставить в URL path

Как это правильно все сделать? Написать скрипт на js, импортировать шифрование, сгенерить данные и подставить в url????

Comment: Не актуально. Реализовал на groovy и js двумя JSR223 Sampler, + загрузил либу crypto-js-4.0.0, и вычисления сложил в глобал-коллекцию.

Answer (score 0):

Не актуально. Реализовал на groovy и js двумя JSR223 Sampler, + загрузил либу crypto-js-4.0.0, и вычисления сложил в глобал-коллекцию.